# Error handling: How can I await and re execute function after a timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to handle async timeouts by awaiting the execution and re-executing a function including error handling after it fails.

**Pseudo code:**

```
01 call and await async function update()
02 if no error -> continue to line 05
03 sleep for 10000ms
04 Jump to line 01 //call update() again and handle possible errors
05 //continues execution
```

seems simple, but I cant get the asynchronous part working

Some common structure **without any promise handling**

```js
let success = false;

while (!success) {
  try{
    update()
    success = true;
  } catch (e) {
    setTimeout(() => {},10000)
  }
}
```

I know that I should be working with .catch and promises, but cant figure out how.

Thanks for any help and explanations

Comment: To add promise handling, just `await`  the promise returned by the `update()` call?

Comment: "*`setTimeout(() => {},10000)`*" - that's not [how to delay a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3583724/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's an example of retrying an async call until success, with a 3 second delay between each attempt:

```js
const wait = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));

let counter = 0;

async function update() {
  console.log('Updating...');
  await wait(1000)
  if (counter === 3) {
    console.log('Update success');
  } else {
    counter += 1;
    throw new Error('Update failure');
  }
}

async function callUpdateUntilSuccess() {
  try {
    await update();
  }catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
    await wait(3000);
    return callUpdateUntilSuccess();
  }
}

(async () => {
  await callUpdateUntilSuccess();
})();
```

Comment: Notice that this works only with synchronous `update` functions

Comment: @Bergi It works with async `update` functions as well. I just updated the example to demonstrate that.

Comment: Ah, but you changed `return` into `await` - that's all I was complaining about :-)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for pointing that out! I did have to make that change.